# Trimming name of the month regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to trim the name of the month if it looks like:

```
September 25th, 2009
```

To:

```
Sept. 25th, 2009
```

BUT - NOT if it looks like this:

```
September 2009
```

I have a regular expression like this. But I do not know the proper way to keep the day of the month as expected either:

```
returnData = "September 5th, 2009";
returnData = returnData.replace("September (\\b\\d{1,2}\\b)th", "Sept. 5th");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `String#replaceAll` with a lookahead:

```
String data = "September 25th, 2009";
String repl = data.replaceAll("^September(?= +\\d+[a-z]{2},)", "Sep.");
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. I'll have to research lookaheads more.

Comment: So - If I change it to {0-2}, just incase there isn't a suffix at the end of the day, would that still work? Example: September 25, 2009.

Comment: I tried this, but for some reason it didn't work? returnData = returnData.replaceAll("^September(?= +\\d+[a-z]{0,2},)", "Sept.");

Comment: Thanks - I might have a data problem then. Or at least a character problem.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is to have an if statement, either in your Java or in the regex itself.

For the latter: http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html